# Is marking as duplicate in a natural language topic a viable solution at all?

Tags: discussion, duplicates

In case of a superficial question, which shows little evidence of research or reasons beyond "would have expected b instead", I see these options:

1. Flag it as low quality. Assessment: low effort, no benefit for others having similar question, educational effect possible
2. Give a "near duplicate" by referring to a question which is close enough to provide sufficient hints for an interested reader. Assessment: medium effort, medium benefit for other having similar question, educational effect possible
3. Adding a comment asking to address the deficiencies. Assessment: medium effort, high benefit for others having similar question (but only if question actually gets improved), educational effect possible
4. Answer it nevertheless. Assessment: high effort, high benefit for others having similar question,  no educational effect (or even one in the wrong direction), if option (3) is not chosen in addition

I don't like option (1) due to lack of benefit, and (4) due to bad balance of effort and education. The comments to [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/40348/1696) make me wonder, whether (2) is really an option on this sub-site. In contrast to programming questions and in absence of a mathematical equivalence proof, some (possibly minor) differences may always exist. So is (3) the only remaining choice, if not willing to invest the effort of (4)?

Comment: I assume that this is only about questions for differences; can you please [edit] your question to clarify? — [You cannot close a question for very low quality.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239688/255554) — *Exact duplicate* is an artefact, don’t bother with it.

Comment: Flagging as low quality is pushing the responsibility (and effort) to others.